# Cordova new project build Error: Error code 1 for command

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-build, android-studio-2.0, phonegap-cli

I have installed fresh cordova and add android platform now when i run "cordova build" command in cmd, it showing an error. screenshot is below

[this is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxuUz.png)

Please help me to solve this

Thank you

Comment: Which version of cordova CLI and android sdk are you using?

Comment: thank u for reply. But now problem is solved after reinstall sdk

Comment: Dude, You have error like "Unsupported major minor.version 52.0" which cause because of incompatible java version please check your cordova version and according to that find java version and install that java and JRE version to your system and try again form start all create and platform add and platform build command for fresh new project.

Comment: Or i think you don't have JAVA installed on your system. Please Install java at least 1.7 and try again from end to end.

Comment: everything was installed. and I have solved the problem. yes it was version related problem. Thank you